# validation for file name entered by the user

Tags: python, validation

```
import os
inF = open(input("Enter Filename: "),'r')
fname = (inF)
if os.path.isfile(fname):
    print("file does exist at this time")
else:
    print("no such file")
```

I wanted to validate if the file the user entered existed but every time the file doesn't exist the error doesn't come up but i get a traceback error instead of the program asking the user to enter the file name egain.

Comment: And the error is...what?

Comment: Hint: `open` does not return a filename, so `fname` is also not a filename.

Comment: when i enter a incorrect filename the program should ask to re-enter the filename but instead it gives me a traceback error

Comment: fname = input("Enter Filename: "), inF = open(fname,'r')  This should work

Comment: Yes...that was pretty clear the first time you typed it. *What* is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tried to open the file before testing for existence

```
import os
import re

fname = input("Enter Filename: ")
if os.path.isfile(fname):
    print("file does exist at this time")
    print("words:", re.findall(r"\w+", open(fname).read()))
else:
    print("no such file")
```

Opening the file right away can be effective if you wrap it in an exception handler. It tests existence and readability in one step

```
try:
    with open(input("Enter Filename: ")) as inF:
        print("file opened okay")
        print("Words:", re.findall(r"\w+", inF.read()))
except OSError as e:
    print("Failed", e)
```

Comment: I was wondering if is it possible to split every word in the text file opened. I know i have to use the .split() function but how do i select the whole text in so it can be splitted?

Comment: @johnsmith you have to read the file first and store it in a variable, and use split() function to that variable.

Comment: .split() doesn't remove punctuation. I'll update the answer with a technique that does.

Answer (score 2):

Because you open it immediately on input; you don't give a chance for the `isfile` function to run.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to open the file object and make a decision if this file exists or not. make `fname = inF.name` This get the name of the file name from the inF object.

```
import os
inF = open(input("Enter Filename: "),'r')
fname = inF.name
if os.path.isfile(fname):
    print("file does exist at this time")
else:
    print("no such file")
```